# How to make cusom conditional Keras function for different labels?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I'm working on a highly imbalanced dataset, and I want to implement different loss functions depending on if the true label is the majority or minority class. Essentially I want to do something like this:

```
def weighted_bce(y_true, y_pred):
    if y_true == 0:
        return binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred,sample_weight = class_weight_dict[0])
    else: 
        return binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred,sample_weight = class_weight_dict[1])
```

But I'm unsure about how to implement it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the weights in a dictionary like below

```
def weighted_bce(y_true, y_pred):

    return binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred,sample_weight = {0: class_weight_dict[0], 1: class_weight_dict[1]})
```

Comment: Doing that results in an error though 

````
 OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed: AutoGraph did not convert this function. Try decorating it directly with @tf.function.
```
Which is a problem I had trying to implement the code in my question

Comment: Sure, the tensorflow version is 2.2.0

Comment: Can you try this one `binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred,sample_weight =[class_weight_dict[0], class_weight_dict[1]])`

Comment: Doing that results in 'InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [32] vs. [2]'

Comment: can you give me more information about your case? Is 32 your batch_size or what?